# Modifying close buttons in Javascript animated panels

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the following javascript to slide open panels to the right when links are clicked.

jQuery(function($) {

```
$('a.panel').click(function() {
    var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
        $other = $target.siblings('.active'),
        animIn = function () {
            $target.addClass('active').show().css({
                left: -($target.width())
            }).animate({
                left: 0
            }, 500);
        };

    if (!$target.hasClass('active') && $other.length > 0) {
        $other.each(function(index, self) {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.removeClass('active').animate({
                left: -$this.width()
            }, 500, animIn);
        });
    } else if (!$target.hasClass('active')) {
        animIn();
    }
});

$('.close').click(function(){        
    $(this).closest('.panel').animate({
                left: -200
            }, 500);
});
```

});

When a close button is clicked the panel is closed.

What I need is that when a close button is clicked, the 'ACTIVE' class is removed from the panel. And IF possible, the anchor is removed.

This is because if the user clicks on the same panel link again it won't open.

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RZpbK/478/)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `.removeClass('active')` to your close function, see http://jsfiddle.net/RZpbK/479/

```
 $('.close').click(function(){        
    $(this).closest('.panel').animate({
                left: -200
            }, 500).removeClass('active');
});
```

As I see it then the function works as expected, but I cant understand why you would want to remove the anchor? Then it cant be closed the next time you open it?

Comment: Ah ok. It works perfectly without removing the anchor as well. I tried adding the .removeClass in some places before but I didn't know exactly where to put it. Thanks a lot.